# Apache retrieve a timeout error and closes connection when uploading large files

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, connection-timeout

I've been trying to reconfigure my `apache` and `php.ini` to allow upload of large file.
therefore I've changed the following variables:
**/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:**

Timeout 7200
ProxyTimeout 7200

**/etc/php.ini:**

```
post_max_size = 1024M         ; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.

max_execution_time = 7200     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds

max_input_time = 7200         ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data

memory_limit =1024M           ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume

file_uploads = On             ; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.

upload_max_filesize = 1024M   ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
```

PHP script - before uploading:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

The response is :

```
324(net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)
```

Please notice that the uploaded file is stored correctly at the server, so the upload process is successful, but I keep getting this error.

Any hint?

Alon kogan

Comment: What browser are you using? Does this error occur in another browser?

Comment: @hohner I'm using Chrome, but the error doesn't relate to a specific browser

Comment: You're getting the exact same error in Firefox? From what I can tell, this is a Chrome error response.

Comment: Internet Explorer after a while presents an Error like "Cannot display the page - check connectivity..."
And firefox return empty page...
Please try this link to fully understand the problem
[upload page](http://projects.e-pay.co.il/upload.php)
It's a script that execute a loop for 20 minutes.

Comment: It looks like your script is entering an infinite loop. You'll need to post some code.

Comment: it's not an infinite loop, it's a 20 minutes loop, it suppose to demonstrate the error i'm getting...

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very late but maybe I'll help someone.

I decided the problem when I lower `memory_limit`

P.S. Sorry for my English